# How to explicitly set a clock-gate signal?

Tags: system-verilog

With various RTL Synthesis tools, clock-gates are inferred. How can I control what clock-gate signal is used from the source code?

---

Example:

```
always @(posedge clk, negedge rst_n) begin
  if (rst_n == 1'd0) begin
    data_r <= '0;
  end else begin
    if (fast_cg_signal) begin
      if (cond_a) begin
        data_r <= data_a;
      end else if (slow_cond_b) begin
        data_r <= data_b;
      end else begin
        data_r <= data_r;
      end
    end
  end
end
```

With this source code, there is a risk that `slow_cond_b` is included in the clock-gate condition, which hurts rtl timing. How can I avoid that and force the synthesis to only use `fast_cg_signal` as the clock-gate condition?

Answers for different toolchains are interesting.

Answer (score 1):

First of all,
The most naive solution is to use a standard cell of the vendor you are using. For example, if you are coding for an ASIC then you can instantiate the template of the actual cell from the vendor (TSMC for example), and connect the signals accordingly (in your case is instantiating a clock gate cell).
Same goes for FPGA (though there it's not clock gate, it's a clock enable).

For example, the next is a template for a FDCE of XILINX FPGA:

```
// FDCE: Single Data Rate D Flip-Flop with Asynchronous Clear and
//       Clock Enable (posedge clk).
//       7 Series
// Xilinx HDL Language Template, version 2023.1

FDCE #(
   .INIT(1'b0) // Initial value of register (1'b0 or 1'b1)
) FDCE_inst (
   .Q(Q),      // 1-bit Data output
   .C(C),      // 1-bit Clock input
   .CE(CE),    // 1-bit Clock enable input
   .CLR(CLR),  // 1-bit Asynchronous clear input
   .D(D)       // 1-bit Data input
);

// End of FDCE_inst instantiation
```

Taken from the next document:

https://docs.xilinx.com/r/en-US/ug953-vivado-7series-libraries/FDCE

If you want the fast signal into the clock enable pin, you connect it to the CE pin.

Now, regarding inference - you can't really control it just by RTL coding, as the tool will do what it sees best as long it meets the behavior you've described in the RTL.

But you can do give the tool directives which defines direct mapping.

(Again, I will give FPGA examples, since the documentation is more open source than ASIC vendors documentations, though it will refer to clock enable and not clock gate.)

In XILINX there is a directive called "DIRECT_ENABLE", that you can add inline the RTL which tells the tool to connect a wire directly to the enable pin of the flop:

[image: Taken from https://docs.xilinx.com/r/en-US/ug1387-acap-hardware-ip-platform-dev-methodology/Using-DIRECT_ENABLE-and-DIRECT_RESET]

**One last note:** Regarding clock gate inference in general, it also depends on more directives that you give the backend tool (minimal number of flops to gate, etc.)